# Finding z score, based on knowing relative size of tails

Tags: probability, distributions, signal-detection

[image: Relevant illustration]
<sub>(source: [duckduckgo.com](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fgru.stanford.edu%2Flib%2Fexe%2Ffetch.php%2Ftutorials%2Fnobias.png%3Fw%3D%26h%3D%26cache%3Dcache&f=1&nofb=1))</sub>

This is based on my looking into signal detection, which deals with two distributions, one "positive," in this case, people who have a certain disease, and one negative, people who do not have that disease. x, in this case, represents a certain load of symptoms related to the disease in question. The decision criteria is the cutoff point of how much information indicating the disease is required before the test assesses a presence of the disease in the case in question. Decision criteria is indicated by c, and is the distance in mean standard deviations from the mean of (mean negative + mean positive)

Given two normal distributions with a difference in means equal to *d'*, and a base rate of *a* I wonder if it is possible to to find a decision criteria if you know the relative rates of False positives/False negatves.

As an example case, which I believe should contain enough information: We know that 1/10 have got a specific disease, and that their symptom score is M: 115, SD: 15. We know that 9/10 have not this disease, but tend to have a certain amount of symptoms that indicate this disease, their symptom score is: M: 85, SD 15. In addition to this, we know that this particular test yields false positives 10 times for every false negative.

Given the case above, is it possible to find the decision criteria of the test? And if so, what would such a formula look like?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to find the threshold $c$ such that the false positive rate is ten times the false negative rate but the numerical value cannot be _explicitly_ defined in terms of elementary functions; it is the solution to an equation that must be solved numerically.

Comment: This is the point I seem to struggle with. While I am able to solve this programatically through manipulating base rate, d' and decision criteria, I cannot seem to find any equations that perform this task already having been worked out. At the moment I'm working backwards from [this](https://www.hostmath.com/Show.aspx?Code=x%3D%20%5Cfrac%7B1-prob(c%2Bd%27%2F2)(1-br)%7D%7Bprob(c-d%27%2F2)br%7D), but don't seem to know how to disentangle it sufficiently to make the c stand on the left side.

Comment: "I cannot seem to find any equations that perform this task already having been worked out".  That's the point; there are no explicit formulas that can be written down of the form $c = \cdots$, only things like "$c$ is the solution to the following transcendental equation."

Comment: Oh, so if I understand it correctly, that would mean that there is no general equation that could be applied in all cases of base rate, d' and decision criteria. So while it is possible to have a formula for a set case, it would change in an unpredictable manner given a change in either variable?